# Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata'

Tags: android, gradle

I uploaded my app on Playstore (bundle.aab method) and it works fine with no errors on android 6.0 but got error on android 7.0 device and doens't run the app. I used the Gradle build classpath 3.1.0 - Trying to solve the problem by updating the Gradle version build to 3.2.0-alpha14' so the compile failed giving me the error message bellow. Does anyone know how may I fix this to make my app run on Android 7.0 devices with Gradle 4.7? Perhaps this upgrade fix the device error I think. Thank you!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'key1'
        keyPassword '*****'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/marco/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "net.panomaps"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 63
        versionName "5.3.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
        implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
        implementation 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'

        implementation 'com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.3.2'

        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


    // error message -> Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata' after configuration ':app:debugApiElements' has been resolved
```

Gradle *distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
    }
}
```

error message -> Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata' after configuration ':app:debugApiElements' has been resolved

Comment: show us the error,how can we help you

Comment: _This is my app_

(https://github.com/marcosnunes/Panomaps)

With *distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip* I got the error mentioned above

With *distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip* I get the error 

` --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-windows Daemon #0`

Answer (score 52):

The issue is related to the google services

After upgrading the firebase versions and / or the gradle plugin version I also had to upgrade the google services plugin version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the culprit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue and was resolved when I updated to the latest versions:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha02'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
```

Comment: Upgrading the google services solved the issue for me

Answer (score 5):

Updating to latest versions didn't help. In our case problem was caused by our custom Gradle task that was resolving dependencies during project configuration.

To locate such tasks first run [Gradle Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/) using `--scan` (e.g. `./gradlew app:assembleDebug --scan`). Then go to the generated scan page, **Performance -> Settings and suggestions**. If there is a warning saying `Dependencies were resolved during project configuration` then you're about to have some fun fixing those.

In our case, it was a custom task that was accessing `variant.javaCompiler.classpath.files` during the configuration step. Try searching for `configurations.` or `.files` in Gradle scripts to find potential culprits and start with commenting those out and re-running the Build Scan to see if the problem is gone.

Following links might help you understand the problem:

- https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#don_t_resolve_dependencies_at_configuration_time
- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/build-scan-argues-about-dependency-resolution-during-project-configuration-may-reduce-build-speed-by-resolving-dependencies-unnecessarily/21583

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error recently:

> Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata' after dependency configuration ':app:playDebugApiElements' has been resolved

I found that the error vanished when I commented out the Android Gradle plugin like so:

```
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.10'
}
```

So I reverted the plugin back to the version 4.0.1 that it was before I updated it, and the error is no more.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the post. I then did "File" > "Sync Project with Gradle Files" and it all worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happens due to plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.orhanobut.tracklytics'
```

Seems it use deprecated api, so I have removed `apply plugin: 'com.orhanobut.tracklytics'`