# Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata' after dependency configuration ':app:myappDebugApiElements' has been resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am updating my project's gradle plugin from 3.2.1 to later versions but i get this error: **Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata' after dependency configuration ':app:myDebugApiElements' has been resolved.**

I tried the suggestions i found at: [Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297502/cannot-create-variant-android-manifest-metadata) , but the problem still persist.

Any one can help me out in this tried a lot still getting the same error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of any one encounter the same issue, i suggest doing the following steps which helped me in solving it in my case:

- first i suggestion looking at the answer given at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376419/9057355

this helped me in getting some hints, after that the problem was caused by a lib plugin in my app level .gradle which was not up to date.

So i started by commenting dependency by dependency and rebuilding the project each time until i found the library which caused the issue.

I suggest to try doing this for each plugin and their associated dependencies.

I whish it may help someone in the future.